# Convexity of affine function.

Tags: convex-analysis, affine-geometry

Can someone help me with a proof that affine function preserves convexity?

Given that $f$ is convex, $A$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$ and $b$ is in $\mathbb{R}^m$ then show that $g(x) = f(Ax+b)$ is convex as well?

thanks in advance

edit: Stefan thanks you for editing my question, (i'm new to the site)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Any starting Idea? We are not here to do your homework, but help you out. I have yet to do this proof, however I guess it can be done by simply using the definitions of convexity and using that $Ax+b$ is a affine transformation.

Comment: As @CBenni said. Why don't you try plugging in the definition of convexity and see what happens? (I assume you rely on the [standard definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition) of convexity.)

Comment: Let me add a hint: The function $g(x)=Ax+b$ satisfies $g(tx+(1-t)y)=tg(x)+(1-t)g(y)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x$, $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. This is the standard definition of affinity, in fact.

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)
&= f( A\lambda x + A(1-\lambda)y + b) \\
&= f(\lambda(Ax+b) + (1-\lambda)(Ay+b)) \\
&\leq \lambda f(Ax+b) + (1-\lambda)f(Ay+b) \\
&=  \lambda g(x) + (1-\lambda)g(y) \\
\end{align}

Hence proved

Comment: Don't you think the third line should be equality?

Comment: Equality will only hold if f(x) is affine. The proof mentioned here is for any general function f(x).

Comment: I have a question about the third line, and I will appreciate it if you answer. If $f(.)$ is affine, can the third line be omitted?